# What is the "linear.predictors" in the result of cox?

Tags: r, cox-regression

I analyzed cox proportional hazard regression with example data.

My R code is below.

```
install.packages("randomForestSRC")
install.packages("survival")
library(randomForestSRC)
library(survival)
data(pbc, package="randomForestSRC")
pbc.na <- na.omit(pbc)

surv.f <- as.formula(Surv(days, status) ~ .)
cox.obj <- coxph(surv.f, data=pbc.na)

cox.obj

cox.obj$linear.predictors
```

What I want to know is that "linear.predictors".

All of the objects in my data seem to have this index, but I have no idea exactly.

Please let me know what it is.

Thans always.

Comment: `?survival::coxph.object` describes the object

Comment: @rawr I've alreadey read the desripction about that. However, it was not detailed. I don't understand what it predicts. As this index has both positive and negative values, it is perhaps not survival probability something like that. Of course not the beta value... I've confused on what this index means.